# svn checkout shows only one file

Tags: linux, subversion

```
anisha@linux-y3pi:~/Desktop/mysvn> svn list https://earthhtml.googlecode.com/svn/
branches/
manual.cpp
ogmap.html
svn-book.pdf
tags/
trunk/
wiki/
```

But, this downloads only one file:

```
anisha@linux-y3pi:~/Desktop/mysvn> svn checkout https://earthhtml.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
Checked out revision 3.

anisha@linux-y3pi:~/Desktop/mysvn> ls
manual.cpp  manual.cpp~  ogmap.html  svn-book.pdf  trunk

anisha@linux-y3pi:~/Desktop/mysvn> cd trunk/
anisha@linux-y3pi:~/Desktop/mysvn/trunk> ls
ogmap.html
```

Why is that so?

http://code.google.com/p/earthhtml/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the directory contains only one file? Your link to the repository web view proves it. The files you listed first are one directory level higher, so if you want all of them, do:

```
svn checkout https://earthhtml.googlecode.com/svn
```

To see the one file with `svn list`, list the contents of the trunk folder:

```
 svn list https://earthhtml.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
```

Compare that with the previous command and it will hopefully be obvious, why you got only one file — you requested only the trunk folder, not the whole repository contents.

Repository structure:

```
branches/
    /.../
manual.cpp
ogmap.html
svn-book.pdf
tags/
    /.../
trunk/
    ogmap.html
wiki/
    /.../
```

`svn checkout` directly copies the structure of the repository (or it would be hard to sync back). If you only specify you want a subfolder, it will only download that; this is known as a partial checkout.

Comment: ofcourse, that's why I have asked the question. `svn list` doesn't show one file. It shows many. How are these things related? Please put the reply in your answer.

Comment: Ah,the address which you showed does download "everything", not just one file. But if you actually click the links you won't see any other file than the html, why is that so?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: I saw that, see if you get the same results by actually clicking on the links in that svn?

Comment: On the web interface? I do. Is the ogmap.html file that's confusing you? It's twice in there, both in / and in trunk.

Comment: Okay, I can swear that I didn't find anything there besides on html file even by clicking on each link. but now I am seeing things. :) .. ah, now I clicked again and I am not seeing things.

Comment: perhaps that page needs refreshes. BTW, can you just add your answer, that how this command decides which files to put in which folders. I had used svn import command.

Comment: as the widget titles say, only directories are shown on the left, while only files are shown on the right list.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something but you only checkout 'trunk' which actually have only one file in its thrid revision, nothing seems strange to me here.
Try `svn checkout https://earthhtml.googlecode.com/svn/` and let us know.

Comment: please see my comment on the other answer.

Comment: Look again at your `svn list` command you are missing `/trunk` at the end of it.

Comment: The address which you showed does download "everything", not just one file. But if you actually click the links you won't see any other file than the html, why is that so?

Comment: Okay, that's my stupidity. :) But still why these files being showed in the website? Are you able to see them?